# Is $X/G$ a complete(projective) variety, when $X$ is a complete(projective) variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a variety (say over $\mathbb{C}$) and $G$ be a finite group acting on $X$. If $X$ is a complete (or projective) variety, does $X/G$ necessarily have the same property?

Comment: Yes in the projective case, not sure about the complete case.

Comment: Actually, complete case also works since a complex variety is complete iff it is compact in analytic topology.

Comment: @studiosus: Can you explain a little bit more on the projective case? Thanks.

Comment: What type of quotient are you taking?

Comment: Geometric quotient, if this is the right terminology.

Comment: I will in a day or so when I have more time. It you can DIY by reading Mumford's GIT  book.

Comment: If the quotient exists (e.g. when $X$ is projective), then $X/G$ is proper (resp. projective) if $X$ is proper (resp. projective). The reason is that the image of proper (resp. projective) variety is proper (resp. projective). When $X$ is proper, the quotient $X/G$ may not exist as variety.

Comment: (1)If $G$ is finite, then the quotient always exists, isn't it right?(2)Suppose $X$ is proper, then $X/G$ is proper if $X \to X/G$ is separted, is this the result you referred to? (3) Could you explain why the image of projective scheme has to be projective?